# Linear Equations Help!

Tags: linear-algebra

For what numbers a and b is the system of equations below satisfied by x =b and y =a?

x - 5 y = a 2

x + 6 y = 36

I've been stuck on this for a while. Thanks in advance for the help. Also I found a lot of the problems online but their explanations just don't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x-5y=a^2, x+6y=36$

Insert $x=b, y=a$ in there and you get $$b-5a=a^2, b+6a=36$$

Now you have a system of two equations with two unknowns.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: replace $(x,y)$ with $(b,a)$ and solve the system. You will find the a and b that you want.